# Coroutine: difference between join() and cancelAndJoin()

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I follow the reference document on Coroutine (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html) and I test in the same time the example on Android Studio (a good boy).

But I am very confuse with cancelAndJoin() method.

If I replace, in the example code, the "cancelAndJoin" with "join", there is no difference in logs.

Here is the code :

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        var nextPrintTime = startTime
        var i = 0
        while (i < 5) { // computation loop, just wastes CPU
            // print a message twice a second
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextPrintTime) {
                println("job: I'm sleeping ${i++} ...")
                nextPrintTime += 500L
            }
        }
    }
    delay(1300L) // delay a bit
    println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
    job.cancelAndJoin() // cancels the job and waits for its completion
    println("main: Now I can quit.")

}
```

and in the 2 cases (with join or cancelAndJoin) the logs are :

```
job: I'm sleeping 0 ...
job: I'm sleeping 1 ...
job: I'm sleeping 2 ...
main: I'm tired of waiting!
job: I'm sleeping 3 ...
job: I'm sleeping 4 ...
main: Now I can quit.
```

Does anybody can explain what is the difference with the 2 methods?

This is not clear because cancel is "stopping the job", join is "waiting for completion", but the two together??? We "stop" and "wait"???

Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 20):

> This is not clear because cancel is "stopping the job", join is
> "waiting for completion", but the two together??? We "stop" and
> "wait"?

Just because we wrote `job.cancel()` doesn't mean that `job` will cancel immediately.

When we write `job.cancel()` the `job` enters a transient `cancelling` state. This `job` is yet to enter the final `cancelled` state and only after the `job` enters the `cancelled` state it can be considered completely cancelled.

[image]

Observe how the state transition occurs,

When we call `job.cancel()` the cancellation procedure(*transition from `completing` to `cancelling`*) starts for the `job`. But we still need to wait, as the `job` is truly cancelled only when it reaches the `cancelled` state. Hence we write `job.cancelAndJoin()`, where `cancel()` starts the cancellation procedure for `job` and `join()` makes sure to wait until the `job()` has reached the `cancelled` state.

Make sure to check out this excellent [article](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-coroutine-job-hierarchy-finish-cancel-and-fail-2d3d42a768a9)

*Note: The image is shamelessly copied from the linked article itself*

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've just realize that my question was stupid!

cancelAndJoin() is equal to do cancel() and then join().

The code demonstrate that the job can not be cancelled if we don't check if it is active or not. And to do so, we must use "isActive".

So like this:

```
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    var nextPrintTime = startTime
    var i = 0
    while (isActive) { // cancellable computation loop
        // print a message twice a second
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextPrintTime) {
            println("job: I'm sleeping ${i++} ...")
            nextPrintTime += 500L
        }
    }
}
delay(1300L) // delay a bit
println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
job.cancelAndJoin() // cancels the job and waits for its completion
println("main: Now I can quit.")
```

Comment: Please don't forget to add reference of the copied code : 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/34262147-kotlin-coroutines-tutorial-for-android-advanced